# Json parsing In Gridview is not Working

Tags: android, json, gridview

i want to show My User (With Image ) in grid view My jSON giving me Correct Response in Array

but After Parsing Json data Are not Showing In Grid view

my Log Cat is Not giving me Any Error 
Just Showing

```
06-05 12:21:12.269: I/Choreographer(4047): Skipped 1134 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

Here Is My Activity

```
public class MeetPeople extends Activity {

private ProgressDialog pDialog;
private GridView gridView;
//private GridViewAdapter customGridAdapter;
// URL to get contacts JSON
private static String url = "http://www.get2love.webitexperts.com/nearbyusers";

// JSON Node names
private static final String TAG_CONTACTS = "";
private static final String TAG_ID = "User_Id";
private static final String TAG_NAME = "User_Full_Name";
private static final String TAG_IMAGE = "User_Image";


// contacts JSONArray
JSONArray contacts = null;

// Hashmap for ListView
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> contactList;
GridViewAdapter customGridAdapter;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.meetpeople);
    //requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

    contactList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    // Calling async task to get json
            new GetContacts().execute();
    //ListView lv = getListView();
    gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView);
    customGridAdapter = new GridViewAdapter(this, R.layout.row_grid, contactList);
    gridView.setAdapter(customGridAdapter);

    gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,int position, long id) {
                        Toast.makeText(MeetPeople.this, position + "#Selected",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                });

}

/**
 * Async task class to get json by making HTTP call
 * */
private class GetContacts extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>> {
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>  contact_List = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        // Showing progress dialog
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MeetPeople.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();

    }

    @Override
    protected ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

         UserModel user = (UserModel) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("User");
        String ID=String.valueOf(user.getUser_Id());
        String DST=String.valueOf(100);
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id",ID));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("distance", DST));
        // Creating service handler class instance
        ServiceHandler sh = new ServiceHandler();

        // Making a request to url and getting response
        String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url, ServiceHandler.POST, params);

        Log.d("Response: ", "> " + jsonStr);

        if (jsonStr != null) {
            try {
                JSONArray contacts = new JSONArray(jsonStr);

                // Getting JSON Array node


                // looping through All Contacts
                for (int i = 0; i < contacts.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = contacts.getJSONObject(i);

                    String User_Id = c.getString(TAG_ID);
                    String User_Full_Name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
                    String User_Image=c.getString(TAG_IMAGE);


                    // Phone node is JSON Object


                    // tmp hashmap for single contact

                    HashMap<String, String> contact = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                    contact.put(TAG_ID, User_Id);
                    contact.put(TAG_NAME, User_Full_Name);
                    contact.put(TAG_IMAGE, User_Image);


                    // adding contact to contact list
                    contact_List.add(contact);

                }
                return contact_List;
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            Log.e("ServiceHandler", "Couldn't get any data from the url");
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(final ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        // Dismiss the progress dialog
        if (pDialog.isShowing())
            pDialog.dismiss();
        contact_List=result;
        gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView);
        customGridAdapter = new GridViewAdapter(MeetPeople.this, R.layout.row_grid, contactList);
        gridView.setAdapter(customGridAdapter);
    /*runOnUiThread( new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            contactList=result;

        }
    });*/

        /**
         * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
         * */
        /*ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                MeetPeople.this, contactList,
                R.layout.row_grid, new String[] { TAG_NAME
                        }, new int[] { R.id.name });

        setAdapter(customGridAdapter);*/
    }

}

}
```

Here IS My GridViewAdaptor

```
public class GridViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private Context context;
private int layoutResourceId;
private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

public GridViewAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId,ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data) {
   // super(context, layoutResourceId, data);
    this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
    this.context = context;
    this.data = data;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View row = convertView;
    ViewHolder holder = null;

    if (row == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
        row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.imageTitle = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.text);
        holder.image = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.image);
        row.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) row.getTag();
    }

  //  ImageItem item = data.get(position);
    holder.imageTitle.setText(getItem(position, "TAG_NAME"));
    holder.image.setImageBitmap(getImage(position));
    return row;
}

static class ViewHolder {
    TextView imageTitle;
    ImageView image;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}

public String getItem(int arg0,String key) {

    return data.get(arg0).get(key);
}
 public Bitmap getImage(int pos){
String  url = data.get(pos).get("TAG_IMAGE");
 MemoryCache memoryCache=new MemoryCache();
 Bitmap bitmap=memoryCache.get(url);
 if(bitmap!=null)
    // imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
     return bitmap;
 else
 {
   // queuePhoto(url, imageView);
   //  imageView.setImageResource(loader);
 }
return null;


}
@Override
public long getItemId(int arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}
 }
```

here Is My Logcat

```
06-05 12:20:47.039: D/StrictMode(4047):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-05 12:20:53.799: D/Response:(4047): >     [{"User_Id":"49","User_Full_Name":"meet","User_Image":""},{"User_Id":"50","User_Full_Name":"meet","User_Image":"http:\/\/www.get2love.webitexperts.com\/profile_images\/1400754860profile.jpg"},{"User_Id":"51","User_Full_Name":"meet","User_Image":"http:\/\/www.get2love.webitexperts.com\/profile_images\/1400756097profile.jpg"},{"User_Id":"71","User_Full_Name":"hh","User_Image":"http:\/\/www.get2love.webitexperts.com\/profile_images\/1401479271profile.jpg"},{"User_Id":"72","User_Full_Name":"hh","User_Image":"http:\/\/www.get2love.webitexperts.com\/profile_images\/1401479340profile.jpg"},{"User_Id":"73","User_Full_Name":"lkjh","User_Image":"http:\/\/www.get2love.webitexperts.com\/profile_images\/1401479662profile.jpg"},{"User_Id":"76","User_Full_Name":"jhon","User_Image":"http:\/\/www.get2love.webitexperts.com\/profile_images\/1401714195profile.jpg"},{"User_Id":"79","User_Full_Name":"sammy","User_Image":"http:\/\/www.get2love.webitexperts.com\/profile_images\/1401889294profile.jpg"}]
 06-05 12:21:12.269: I/Choreographer(4047): Skipped 1134 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
 06-05 12:21:38.829: I/Choreographer(4047): Skipped 1533 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

can anyone please Solve My Problem I Want Show these reSponse In GridView (UserImage)

please and thanks in adavance

my new logcat after editing in code....as per ansewer

```
06-05 13:22:22.849: E/Trace(8790): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
06-05 13:23:41.839: E/Buffer Error(8790): Error converting result java.lang.NullPointerException
```

06-05 13:23:41.839: E/JSON Parser(8790): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of 
    06-05 13:23:51.759: E/AndroidRuntime(8790): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
     06-05 13:23:51.759: E/AndroidRuntime(8790): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
     06-05 13:23:51.759: E/AndroidRuntime(8790):    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
     06-05 13:23:51.759: E/AndroidRuntime(8790):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
     06-05 13:23:51.759: E/AndroidRuntime(8790):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
     06-05 13:23:51.759: E/AndroidRuntime(8790):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
    06-05 13:23:51.759: E/AndroidRuntime(8790):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
    06-05 13:23:51.759: E/AndroidRuntime(8790):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
    06-05 13:23:51.759: E/AndroidRuntime(8790):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
    06-05 13:23:51.759: E/AndroidRuntime(8790):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
     06-05 13:23:51.759: E/AndroidRuntime(8790):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
    06-05 13:23:51.759: E/AndroidRuntime(8790): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    06-05 13:23:51.759: E/AndroidRuntime(8790):     at com.example.phonebook.MainActivity$loginAccess.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:149)
    06-05 13:23:51.759: E/AndroidRuntime(8790):     at com.example.phonebook.MainActivity$loginAccess.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:1)
     06-05 13:23:51.759: E/AndroidRuntime(8790):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
     06-05 13:23:51.759: E/AndroidRuntime(8790):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
    06-05 13:23:51.759: E/AndroidRuntime(8790):     ... 5 more
    06-05 13:23:52.309: E/WindowManager(8790): Activity com.example.phonebook.MainActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@420415a0 that was originally added here
06-05 13:23:52.309: E/WindowManager(8790): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.example.phonebook.MainActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@420415a0 that was originally added here
        06-05 13:23:52.309: E/WindowManager(8790):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.(ViewRootImpl.java:374)
       06-05 13:23:52.309: E/WindowManager(8790):   at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:292)
     06-05 13:23:52.309: E/WindowManager(8790):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:224)
    06-05 13:23:52.309: E/WindowManager(8790):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl$CompatModeWrapper.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:149)
    06-05 13:23:52.309: E/WindowManager(8790):  at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:547)
    06-05 13:23:52.309: E/WindowManager(8790):  at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:277)
    06-05 13:23:52.309: E/WindowManager(8790):  at com.example.phonebook.MainActivity$loginAccess.onPreExecute(MainActivity.java:139)
        06-05 13:23:52.309: E/WindowManager(8790):  at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:586)
       06-05 13:23:52.309: E/WindowManager(8790):   at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:534)
       06-05 13:23:52.309: E/WindowManager(8790):   at com.example.phonebook.MainActivity$2.onClick(MainActivity.java:112)
       06-05 13:23:52.309: E/WindowManager(8790):   at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4084)
       06-05 13:23:52.309: E/WindowManager(8790):   at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:16987)
     06-05 13:23:52.309: E/WindowManager(8790):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
   06-05 13:23:52.309: E/WindowManager(8790):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
    06-05 13:23:52.309: E/WindowManager(8790):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    06-05 13:23:52.309: E/WindowManager(8790):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4794)
     06-05 13:23:52.309: E/WindowManager(8790):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    06-05 13:23:52.309: E/WindowManager(8790):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    06-05 13:23:52.309: E/WindowManager(8790):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
     06-05 13:23:52.309: E/WindowManager(8790):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:556)
      06-05 13:23:52.309: E/WindowManager(8790):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go back to your original code which had was setting a Grid Adapter with an empty contact list. That should get rid of the null pointer exception. Add a method called callNotifyDataChanged in your GridViewAdapter.java and the below code.

```
public void callNotifyDataChanged() {
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

in GetContacts.onPostExecute method, call this after you set the adapter again.

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(final ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);
....
....



customGridAdapter.callNotifyDataChanged() ;
```

Ideally, you don't have to recreate the adapter and set it again. You should be only changing the data in the adapter and reuse the same adapter. But first, try what I suggested and see if it works.

Good luck

Comment: One thing though. Looks like you are actually getting a JSONException while parsing. This code will not help if there is issue parsing and preparing the contactlist. You may want to put a breakpoint in the json parsing code and find out what exactly is happening.

Comment: 06-05 13:53:41.901: E/Trace(20080): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
06-05 13:54:31.641: E/Trace(20627): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)

not Showing After Debugging ..Showing this Error In LogCat ..@Raghu

Comment: I m Getting Response Correctly In result.{all Users )

Comment: But you can clearly see the error in your log. "Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0". Do one thing. You are already printing what you are getting from the server. Why don't you print each JSONObject as you loop through the JSONArray. In side the for (int i = 0; i < contacts.length(); i++) {... after you get each string, print them to the log and see what you are getting.

Comment: Can U post Ur Explaination Actually i m new and I m very Confuse ...so plzzzz

Comment: If you read the log, you will see that there is a JSONException that is causing your async task to terminate. The only way this can happen is if you are trying to parse an invalid JSON string. What I suggested before was the moment you get the JSONArraycheck if it is null and use Log.d and print some message. Similarly, in the loop, after you get all the strings, print one line displaying each value. The other option is to set a breakpoint in this loop and fire off your debugger.

Comment: Raghu Bro ...Its Working And Thnxx for ...Its getting imageloader prob ..can u tell Me How TO USe Universal Image Loader ..

Comment: I am glad it worked out for you. I haven't used ImageLoader but here is a tutorial that should help (http://cbpbenitez.blogspot.com/2013/11/universal-image-loader-tutorial.html)

Answer (score 0):

Remove

```
customGridAdapter = new GridViewAdapter(this, R.layout.row_grid, contactList);
gridView.setAdapter(customGridAdapter);
```

from `onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {`. and

```
gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView);
```

from `onPostExecute(..)` 
beside initialize `gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView);` before

```
new GetContacts().execute();
```

Comment: thanks for responding But After Removing This app Stopped ..

giving me error ..

caused by null pointer

Comment: The reason for the null pointer exception is because you are now setting a null grid adapter to gridview. I think your original problem was the fact that you were not using notifyDataSetChanged to let the view know that there is new data. After setting the adapter in gridview, call notifyDataSetChanged.

Comment: @user3709878...not Working After Doing This ..Giving Lots of Error 

How to Show Logcat In Comment ?

Comment: @Raghu Bro Can you explanin and Provide me Code please

Comment: @user3384985  .not Working After Doing This ..Giving Lots of Error How to Show Logcat In Comment ?

Comment: please mention the code where error is causing and which error

Comment: Try this. Hard to put the code here. I am adding a new answer.

Comment: @Raghu ok bro  i m waiting but Please provide me